# Phonegap FileTransfer Upload Returning Null

Tags: android, cordova

I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now. The tutorials and documents all say the same thing.

I want to upload a photo the user takes with the camera. However, it keeps hitting the error function and saying code, source, and target are null. My server never gets hit and there seems to be nothing about it. Here is my code.

```
$(function() {

$('#camera').click(function() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(upload, function() {
        alert('error');
    },
    {
        quality: 50, 
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
    }); 
});

var upload = function(image) {

    console.log(image);

    var options = new FileUploadOptions()
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=image.substr(image.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    console.log(image.substr(image.lastIndexOf('/')+1));

    options.chunkedMode = true;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(image, encodeURI("http://mysite/upload.php"), win, fail, options);

};

function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}

});
```

config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: Do you get anything in logcat? What version of cordova are you using? Did you make sure to add the file and file-transfer plugins?

Comment: Show your server code

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Telerik platform by any chance? If so, that would be the reason. This platform is currently limited in some aspects and does not support the File and File Transfer API. Here's a list of limitations of the simulator. That is why FileTransfer would return null instead of an error code.

http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/testing-your-app/running-apps-in-simulator/limitations-device-simulator